# SQL inserts slowing down with ADO when reaching some threshhold

Tags: sql, sql-server, delphi

I use ADO to fire up this query:

```
INSERT INTO mytable (a,b) VALUES
(1,a)
,(2,b)
..
,(900,zzz)
```

I first put it in a stringlist, and then use ADOQuery.SQL.Text := sl.Text to get it all in the querycomponent at once.
This inserts 900 records at once. I use this to speed up insertion of data in the database. I can scale it up to 100.000 records which it will do in about 4 seconds. But, when I try 200.000 records it suddenly takes very long. I used queryanalyzer and suddenly it slows down to a crawl, each of the queries take 1-2 seconds to fire. This happens when there are about 150.000 records inserted. Is there a setting I can do to either ADO or the SQL server to keep my speed?

I use a MS SQL database.

Comment: What are the auto-growth settings on your database?

Comment: I increased autogrow, first from 10MB to 100MB, now the problem starts at 180k records inserted, then I increased it to 1000MB and the problem starts at 200k.

Comment: I think this issue comes from INSERT logging and log file growth. Try to use WITH (TABLOCK). Also you can split your statement in many INSERTs with up to 100k records in one transaction. [link](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190422.aspx)

Comment: may it be indices rebuilding after inserts ?
for interbase/firebird common topic is to de-activate all indices on all affected tables before mass insert (all tables for there can eb triggers as well), commit data and then re-activate indices. Thus last step would spent a lot of time and space sorting them, but will only done once then.

Comment: You should also post your server configuration, OS, RAM etc.

Comment: A database never "stores all in memory" - or an outage will trash it. Databases uses log files to store changes until they are committed. To insert large number of records at once usually there are some ETL functions that bypass some of the standard query processing.

Comment: Try this without ADO (for instance with DBExpress) and without Delphi (for instance with SQL Server Management Studio) to see how it reproduces. Then post the minimum reproducible case. If this is server side, then also post what kind and version of SQL server you have, what OS it runs on, what kind of hardware it runs on, etc.